# VC++ merge multiple COM DLLs into one

Tags: visual-c++, dll, merge

Let's say we have multiple libraries (DLLs) whose features one wants to use in an application, and wants to use them as a single DLL.

Is it possible to merge the DLLs into a single one, with all the features packed into it? I am not looking at the option to write a wrapper.

EDIT:

I've revisited the problem. Now all I want to do is bring all the projects under one solution and get a single DLL as the output instead of each project having it's independant output. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145499/merge-several-native-dlls-into-one-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't literally merge several compiled .dll files into one. Your best bet is to put all files into a single project and recompile as a single library. You will likely have conflicts you'll have to resolve manually.

If you really have several COM in-proc servers you will also have to merge the data that facilitates class factories and COM registration - you will have to do that manually.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. was hoping against hope that I'll get a better option...

Comment: @Whiskey-Tango-Foxtrot: Yes, I understand. But really "merging" several .dll files into one is almost the same as merging several .exe files into one - just can't be done. However recompiling is likely not that hard, just don't try to go the static libraries way.