# C# DLL Wrapper Concrete way

Tags: c#, dll, wrapper

I got many .dll files for my project.
It is quite troublesome that moving a lot of .dll around for a project.

Is there any simple method to group many .dll file into one?

I heard something call dll wrapper but I cannot find out any concrete method related to it.

Can anyone give me a hand please.

Thank you very much.

By the way, all my .dll files and project are written in C#.

Comment: Try looking at the answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145499/merge-several-native-dlls-into-one-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) utility

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly.

Comment: -1. Nothing againt IlMerge where it makes sense, but here the problem is more a lazy developer overwhelmed by the fact that he has more than one dll - and a problem that simply most people will fail to even see. Also, IlMerge in general use ccreates problems (only ONE HUGH file intead of reusable modules, or no way to isntall parts into GAC). Again, I like it, but i think it is a wrong approach here. Fixing the issue at hand is more important.

Comment: @TomTom, I think you should -1 the question, not the answer. Nothing wrong with the answer itself. ILMerge does have its uses, albeit in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

> It is quite troublesome that moving a lot of .dll around for a project.

Really? Define many. I have projects consolidating 50ü+ dll#s and you know what - it is trivial to move them. Scripts, installers all do that automatically. Including configuring a dozen build server agents with the necessary copies etc.

Really, the only time I have to copy thm around is when I deploy manually to another machine for hotfixing or manual testing. I do that quite a lot at the moment (develop local, copy / paste the folder content to another machine to run tests - faster and closer to the database). Trivial. if it gets more work, I put in a little script. Trivial again.

Being a programmer is not about just knowing how to write some small classes, it also involves optimizting your environment a little. In times of CI (Continuous integration) and pretty much mandatory installers knowing more than just your programming langauge is a must. And then this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You could unite your DLLs into a single multi-module assembly, or just create one giant C# project that includes all the DLL source files and compiles everything into a single DLL.

However, what's the problem with moving several DLLs around?